# Mocking a class with Rx extensions

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols, rx-swift

Im trying to achieve dependency injection with protocols in Swift :)

My system under test calls .rx.signIn() on the dependency, meaning that it has extended Reactive where Base : ConcreteObject.

Is it possible to setup a protocol ready to receive .rx calls?

Any small example or alternative would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem during the upgrade from RxSwift2 to RxSwift3. In RxSwift2 I simply used a protocol for the rx-methods in my production code (ex. rx_JSON()) and injected a simple mock object adhering to that protocol in my unit tests.

After a short detour into generics, associated type and type erasure I settled with the following setup, which closely matches my RxSwift2-setup:

For example to hide URLSession as the concrete implementation of my HTTP-calls, I created a protocol RemoteClient:

```
protocol RemoteClient {
    func json(url: URL) -> Observable<Any>
}
```

Then in my production code I reference only that protocol:

```
class SomeService {
    var remoteClient: RemoteClient

    init(remoteClient: RemoteClient) {
        self.remoteClient = remoteClient
    }

    func getSomeData(_ id: String) -> Observable<JSONDictionary> {
        let urlString = "..."

        return remoteClient
            .json(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
            .map { data in
                guard let show = data as? JSONDictionary else {
                    throw ParsingError.json
                }

                return show
            }
    }
}
```

In my unit tests I created mock objects which adhere to the RemoteClient protocol:

```
class RemoteClientMock: RemoteClient {

    var output: Any?
    var verifyInput: ((URL) -> Void)?

    func json(url: URL) -> Observable<Any> {
        verifyInput?(url)

        return Observable.create { observer in
            if let data = self.output {
                observer.on(.next(data))
            }

            observer.on(.completed)

            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
}
```

And inject them in the system under test:

```
class SomeServiceTest: TestCase {

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()


    func testGetSomeData() {
        // setup
        let expectation = self.expectation(description: "request succeeded")

        let remoteClientMock = RemoteClientMock()
        remoteClientMock.verifyInput = { url in
            XCTAssertEqual(URL(string: "some url"), url)
        }
        remoteClientMock.output = ["id": 4711]

        let service = SomeService(remoteClient: remoteClientMock)

        // exercise
        let observable = service.getSomeData("4711")

        // verify
        observable
            .subscribe(onNext: { data in
                XCTAssertEqual(4711, data["id"] as? Int)
                expectation.fulfill()
            })
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

        waitForExpectations(timeout: 1, handler: nil)
    }
}
```

So I simply hide the rx-namespace behind my protocol. I do that for now by using an adapter:

```
let remoteClient = URLSessionRemoteClientAdapter(urlSession: URLSession.shared)
let service = SomeService(remoteClient: remoteClient)

struct URLSessionRemoteClientAdapter: RemoteClient {
    let urlSession: URLSession

    init(urlSession: URLSession) {
        self.urlSession = urlSession
    }

    func json(url: URL) -> Observable<Any> {
        return urlSession.rx.json(url: url)
    }
}
```